# CAPL - TestStepInconclusive - "function is not allowed within the current context"

Tags: automated-tests, capl

I´m all the time using TestStep with TestStepPass, Fail and Warning so I thought that TestStepInconclusive  would work the same way but it´s not compiling, saying that it´s not allowed within the current context (I tried using it as the other ones, for example: 
 if(ok>0) TestStepInconclusive()
) - the idea is that the test expects some manual steps so I want to run a small automation but not have a Pass or Fail as final evaluation of the test. 
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

`testStepInconclusive` can only be used in test units and not in test modules, i.e. only when you are using vTESTstudio

Comment: Thank you, I see!